# Is their way, I can open a putty session and execute the commands written in the code below; (don't not share pywinauto examples)

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the source code which I created on python, however, unable to run from window machine.

If I use the same on Ubuntu, it works well.

Is their way, I can open a putty session and execute the commands written in the code below;

```
HOST = " 192.168.15.101"
user = input("Enter your device username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("enable\n")
tn.write("cisco\n")
tn.write("conf t\n")
tn.write("interface loop 1\n")
tn.write("ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255\n")
tn.write("interface loop 2\n")
tn.write("ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.255\n")
tn.write("interface loop 3\n")
tn.write("ip address 1.1.1.3 255.255.255.255\n")
tn.write("interface loop 4\n")
tn.write("ip address 1.1.1.4 255.255.255.255\n")
tn.write("end\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print(tn.read_all())
```

Comment: When you will have added the code, can you show us the stacktrace ? (or any error raised when trying to launch the script on Windows)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? And yup, for sure you can open putty session and run python from the console.